# Some C# 9 features not available after upgrading Asp.Net Core 3.1 app to .Net 5

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-5, c#-9.0

I've upgraded an Asp.Net Core 3.1 (MVC) to .Net 5 by modifying the corresponding *.csproj file to this:

```
<TargetFramework>net5.0</TargetFramework>
<LangVersion>9.0</LangVersion>
```

Now I can use the C# 9 [target typing feature](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/welcome-to-c-9-0/#target-typed-new-expressions)...

```
string s = new('c', 3); // compiles fine
```

...but I can't create a [*record* class](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/welcome-to-c-9-0/#records):

```
public data class User
{
  // IDE1007 The name 'data' does not exist in the current context. 
}
```

Am I missing something here?

Comment: While it is good that Microsoft and the C# team is now posting feature suggestions and work on bringing them to life as they go along, it is important to remember that most of the articles you find have been written *before* the feature was finalized. As such it is important to know that features that are in-progress tend to change, and this was one of them. The `data class` syntax was replaced with `record` at some point.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

According to [record type specs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/whats-new/csharp-9#record-types), you should use `public record User` syntax.

It's better to look at final specs rather then blog post with introduction, since some things were changed.

You can also refer to [csharplang repo](https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang) in GitHub to check the most recent specs, design meetings and proposals. For particular *Records* feature the initial issue [#39](https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/issues/39) might be used to track the most recent updates and specs

Comment: But aren't record types and data members two different things? Data members are a new way to define immutable types. Documents suggest that in the data member classes you just need to define the properties like private fields.

Answer (score 2):

The keyword for [records types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/whats-new/csharp-9#record-types) is `record` now:

```
public record Person
{
    public string LastName { get; }
    public string FirstName { get; }

    public Person(string first, string last) => (FirstName, LastName) = (first, last);
}
```