# How to use `Data members` in C#-9

Tags: c#-9.0, record-classes

I was trying the new syntax for C# 9 but I failed to use the [Data members](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/welcome-to-c-9-0/comment-page-2/#data-members).

Documents say the syntax is:

```cs
public data class Person { string FirstName; string LastName; }
```

However, I faced the following compile errors:

```
CS0116: A namespace cannot directly contain members such as fields or methods
IDE1007: The name 'data' does not exist in the current context.
```

I have tried other syntaxes and they all worked. So, I am sure that I am using C#-9

#### Update: [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64821207/some-c-sharp-9-features-not-available-after-upgrading-asp-net-core-3-1-app-to-n) is suggested as a possible answer.

But, it is not my answer and I believe the accepted answer in that link is wrong. Record types and data members are two different things. Data members are a new way to define immutable types, while the record types are Value Objects.
Documents suggest that in the data member classes you just need to define the properties like private fields, so the `Person` is equal to:

```cs
public data class Person
{
    public string FirstName { get; init; }
    public string LastName { get; init; }
}
```

Comment: Are you using a fully-updated IDE and .Net 5.0 or newer?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Some C# 9 features not available after upgrading Asp.Net Core 3.1 app to .Net 5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64821207/some-c-sharp-9-features-not-available-after-upgrading-asp-net-core-3-1-app-to-n)

Comment: @McAden, yes I have updated everything. My IDE is  `16.8.1` and I am using other syntaxes.

Comment: @IvanStoev Thank you for suggesting that but no it is not my answer and I believe the accepted answer in that link is wrong.
Record types and data members are two different things. Data members are a new way to define immutable types, while the record types are Value Objects. Documents suggest that in the data member classes you just need to define the properties like private fields.

Comment: data classes are now called records. They are the same, immutable objects which behave like value types (exhibiting structural or in other words value based equality). the data keyword has been replaced with record now.

Comment: So at the end it *is* a duplicate of the aforementioned post, and the accepted answer in that link is correct :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`data` classes are now called `record`. They are the same, immutable objects which behave like value types (exhibiting structural or in other words value based equality).

Regarding your code in OP,

```
public data class Person { string FirstName; string LastName; }
```

could be rewritten as

```
public record Person(string FirstName, string LastName);
```

The above syntax uses *Primary Constructor* . If you would like to skip the primary constructor, you could also declare records as

```
public record Person
{
    public string FirstName { get; init; }
    public string LastName { get; init; }
}
```

In either cases, the Properties, FirstName and LastName could be assigned only during initialization (either via Constructor or object initializers) and not after that.